# Can I change an object's type inside its own methods?

Tags: ruby, object, type-conversion

It would be great if I could change an object's class inside its own methods like:

```
class Dog < Animal
  def initialize(color, size)
    #do some stuff
  end
  def do_lots_of_stuff
    #really long involved calculations with different classes and methods 
    #and objects that I can't really change at this point
    if random_condition
      self = Super_Special_Dog.new(@color, @size, specialness)
    end
  end
end

class Super_Special_Dog < Dog
  def initialize(color, size, specialness)
    #do stuff
  end
end
```

Is there a way to convert an instance of `Dog`, say 'fido', into `Super_Special_Dog` so that after `fido.do_lots_of_stuff` is called, `fido.is_a? Super_Special_Dog` will return `true` and other methods/classes can operate on fido with `Super_Special_Dog`'s methods and variables from then on?

I tried the above structure and got an error `Can't change the value of self (SyntaxError)`. I can make `Super_Special_Dog` based on `Dog` or on `Animal` it doesn't matter for my needs.

I can see some other questions about converting the object outside its own methods but I need to do it inside. I already have about 2k-3k lines of code all intertwined that would be hard to change at this point.

Comment: No, you can't change an instance's class. This may be what's called an ["XY" question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which seem to be appearing on SO with increasing regularity. (XY questions are bad, not good.) What is the problem you want to solve by changing an instance's class?

Comment: I think the shortest way to go is to throw out your 2k-3k lines of intertwined code, which is presumably a junk, and start over.

Comment: 1st. XY questions are a direct result of being told "Well tell us what you tried before we help you."

Comment: I've written the whole thing over the last 2-3 weeks.I'm so close to being done but there's this one issue where I had trouble with a certain kind of "Dog" objects.

Comment: Your frustration comes through loud and clear. I didn't mean to be harsh, and perhaps shouldn't have been flippant, but I genuinely wanted to know what the problem is that you are struggling with, so that readers could offer useful suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, it's just most of the time I try to ask anything on here it gets closed asap so I was ready to argue why it should stay open. :)  I really was thinking that I had to give my implementation before anyone would answer especially since it's kind of hard for me to explain the situation without an example.

Comment: If you need any help framing questions, feel free to send me an email. Address is in my profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, no one should care whether fido is a `Dog` or a `Super_Special_Dog` - they should only care what tricks fido can do (that is, what methods he responds to). That's the duck-typing (dog-typing?) way to do things.

If you remove the requirement that the actual class needs to be changed, it's trivial to add new functionality to an instance from inside itself.

```
class Dog
  def become_special
    @special = true
    extend SpecialTraits
  end
end

module SpecialTraits
  def do_special_thing
  end
end

fido = Dog.new
rex = Dog.new

fido.become_special

fido.do_special_thing # Okay!
rex.do_special_thing # NoMethodError
```

Comment: Thanks Max. I Like this. This is my first time using Ruby so I'm kind of just picking things up as I go along and I haven't used modules much. This seems like it works and the @special flag would be easy to test later. I think "do_special_thing" would still work right if it was passed down from super classes. Thanks :)

Comment: Note that `extend` inserts the module into the object's ancestors as well. So `fido.is_a? SpecialTraits` is true. Superclasses shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

You can't change an object's class, but you *can* mix in additional modules and methods. There are a number of ways to do this; one way is through adding singleton methods to individual instances.

### Dynamic Singleton Methods on Instances

You can dynamically define methods on specific instances with [Object#define_singleton_method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method). For example:

```
class Dog; end

rover = Dog.new
spot  = Dog.new
fido  = Dog.new

# Give Rover and Spot a new method dynamically.
[rover, spot].each do |dog|
  dog.define_singleton_method(:bark) { 'Woof! Woof!' }
end

# Only Rover and Spot have the new method; Fido is a barkless dog.
[rover, spot, fido].map { |dog| dog.respond_to? :bark }
#=> [true, true, false]
```

Comment: This is nice if you only have a small extra method to add but in my situation I have a bunch of variables, and methods to add to the special cases. I would get confused which were normal and which were singleton later. And I'm not sure if bark were an inherited method would that work? Like if `Dog` were an `Animal` and `Animal` had `Animal.bark` would it find the singleton method `bark`?